# jQuery how to detect id of li element loaded from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a `ul` element which holds `li` elements that were loaded from a `json` file. I want to pass some data located inside that json file to another page (jquery mobile page), according to the `id` of the `li` element that was clicked. For some reason I cant make it work. What am I missing?

This is the structure of my `json` file.

```
    {
        "abc":
         [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Nikola Tesla",
                "image": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Tesla_circa_1890.jpeg/640px-Tesla_circa_1890.jpeg",
                "price": "100"
            }
        ]
}
```

HTML code:

```
             <!--PAGE WITH A LIST OF SCIENTISTS -->
<div data-role="page" id="scientists">
    <div data-role="header"><h3>great scientists</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
            <div>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" id="namesListView"></ul>
             </div>
     </div>
 </div>

                <!--A PAGE WITH all details about selected SCIENTIST -->
<div data-role="page" id="sc">
    <div id="details_of_selected"></div>
        <img id="pic" src=""/>
</div>
```

I'm able to detect clicks on the list of `li`s, but cant extract the `id` of the element.

```
$(document).on('click','#namesListView',function(){
    console.log("li was clicked");
});
```

the code that loads the data from the `json` to the `li`s

```
$.ajax({
    url:"scientists.json",
    dataType:"json",
    type:"get",
    cache:"false",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(data.abc).each(function(index,value){
            console.log(value.name);
            $("#namesListView").append("<li><a href='#sc' data-rel='dialog'>"+value.name+"</a></li>");
        });
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#namesListView').listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for simple question... have you added IDs to each of the elements in the UL when you have loaded it?  If there are no IDs then jQuery would return blank.

Comment: the `li`'s dont have id, only the elements inside the `li`s have attributes, such as id.

Comment: Okay your question stated "according to the id of the li element that was clicked".  LIs don't have an ID of their own.  You maybe able to get indexes.  I will give an answer below.

Comment: Had an idea to use the index of the object in the abc array instead.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to add the index of the data in the array retrieved from the JSON.

```
$(data.abc).each(function(index,value){
            console.log(value.name);
            $("#namesListView").append("<li data-index='" + index + "'><a href='#sc' data-rel='dialog'>"+value.name+"</a></li>");
        });
```

Now you can do this:

```
$(document).on('click','#namesListView',function(){
    var myIndex = $(this).data('index'); 
})
```

and I would add a variable as well to hold your data;

```
var abc = [];
```

so you can get to the data you want. So in it's entirity:

```
var abc = [];
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"scientists.json",
        dataType:"json",
        type:"get",
        cache:"false",
        success:function(data){
            abc = data.abc;
            $(abc).each(function(index,value){
                console.log(value.name);
                $("#namesListView").append("<li data-index='" + index + "'><a href='#sc' data-rel='dialog'>"+value.name+"</a></li>");
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#namesListView').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click','#namesListView li',function(){ //  change here so you are clicking on an LI and not the parent UL element.
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    alert(abc[index].name);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#namesListView',function(){
    var myId = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but when I print `myId`'s value in the console it's the name of the `ul` list (namesListView).

Comment: Well, I don't see any <li>s in the code your provided. If you had some of them and they were clicked, it would return their id attribute.

Comment: I have added the code that loads the data inside the `li`. How can i add the `id` from the `json` to the `li` thats holding it (so the `li` will have the same `id` as the data inside the `json`)?

Comment: when you suggest any answer please try to include some kind of explanations too in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
    var data = {
        "abc":
         [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Nikola Tesla",
                "image": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Tesla_circa_1890.jpeg/640px-Tesla_circa_1890.jpeg",
                "price": "100"
            }
        ]
};
$.ajax({
    // url:"/echo/json/",
    dataType:"json",
    type:"POST", // "GET"
    cache:"false",
    // data: {json : JSON.stringify(data)},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $(data.abc).each(function(index,value){
            console.log(value.name);
            // add `id` to `li`
            $("#namesListView").append("<li id="+value.id+"><a href='#sc' data-rel='dialog'>"+value.name+"</a></li>");
        });
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#namesListView').listview('refresh');
    }
});
    $(document).on('click','#namesListView',function(e) {
    // `log` `id` of parent `li`
    console.log($(e.target).parent("li").attr("id"));
});
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6tdzZ/

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the whole item to li's data attribute like this:

```
data.abc.forEach(function(value){

    var $myLi = $('<li></li>');
    var $innerAnchor = $("<a href='#sc' data-rel='dialog'>"+value.name+"</a>");

    $myLi
        .data(value)
        .html($innerAnchor);

    $("#namesListView").append($myLi);

});
```

Or pass just some values like this:

```
data.abc.forEach(function(value){

    var $myLi = $('<li></li>');
    var $innerAnchor = $("<a href='#sc' data-rel='dialog'>"+value.name+"</a>");
    var dataToPass = {
        id: value.id,
        name: value.name
    };

    $myLi
        .data(dataToPass)
        .html($innerAnchor);

    $("#namesListView").append($myLi);
});
```

and access it later like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#namesListView li',function(){

    // the li element contains all scientist data

    var scientistDetails = $(this).data();
    console.log(scientistDetails.name, scientistDetails);     

});
```

your example would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"scientists.json",
        dataType:"json",
        type:"get",
        cache:"false",
        success:function(data){

            data.abc.forEach(function(value){

                var $myLi = $('<li></li>');
                var $innerAnchor = $("<a href='#sc' data-rel='dialog'>"+value.name+"</a>");

                $myLi
                  .data(value)
                  .html($innerAnchor);

                $("#namesListView").append($myLi);
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#namesListView').listview('refresh');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','#namesListView li',function(){

        // the li element contains all scientist data

        var scientistDetails = $(this).data();
        console.log(scientistDetails.name, scientistDetails);     

    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c3AvL/